# Clean Implementation showing popup Error messages in MVVM ViewModel

Tags: wpf, silverlight, design-patterns, mvvm, messagebox

I want to be able to show popups with errors and warnings. These originate from my `ViewModel` and other utilities in my application.
I have a static class `MessageBoxHelper` that provides this functionality for me.

I now do encounter a problem with my testability. In cases where i want to verify failing loging my test trigger the `MessageBox` and i get a `UI thead exception` in my Test.

I want to achieve a loose coupling system that's clean with a little overhead to provide this functionality.  I allready came up with 2 idea's but for me there is still to much downside:

1. Implementing the Interface `IMessageBoxHelper` registered in my `DI Container`. This required me to add another parameter to my `Constructor`. And i want to avoid having a gigantic constructor.
2. Instead of calling the `MessageBoxHelper` directly sending a message with my `EventAggregator` and implementing a `MessageBoxListener` as singleton catching these `Messages` and showing them.  But this seems a bit over-engeneerded to me.

Is any of these idea's right or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your view model has a dependency on being able to show a message box (e.g. `IMessageBoxHelper`) why not make that obvious by injecting the dependency? Unit testing will be easy etc. I don't see a problem in choosing solution 1.

Comment: I allready have 4 dependencies to other Service Interfaces. Shouldn't i try to avoid having this size?

Comment: @Jeroen: Five dependencies doesn't sound like a lot. Off course, if your view model is bloated and monolithic you should consider refactoring it but I doubt that is the case.